# Override @JoinColumn nullable value

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I have a lot of mapped entities, and all of them extends from an abstract class `BaseEntityImpl`.

In this class, I have 1 attribute company, annotated like this:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_company", nullable = false)
public Company getCompany() {
    return company;
}
```

In only one of the subclasses ( `Company` to be precise), I want this attribute to be NULLEABLE.

But overriding the setter

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "id_company", nullable = true)
@Override
public Company getCompany() {
    return company;
}
```

leads me to this error:

*Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Duplicate property mapping of company found in ar.com.test.entity.Company*

Is there any way, besides not extending for this class, and explicitly defining all attributes/getters/setters in the Company class to achieve this?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried looking at [@AssociationOverride](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/AssociationOverride.html)?

```
@Entity
@AssociationOverride(name="company",
                     joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id_company", nullable=true))
public class Company extends BaseEntityImpl {
   ....
}
```

Comment: Thank you @mtpettyp, it work like a charm (I always wanted to say that!!).